# UIImage Size Property Returning Pixel Dimensions Instead of Points

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimageref, video-toolbox

I'm taking a **CVImageBufferRef** from the camera output, then converting it to a **CGImageRef** with **VideoToolbox**, then converting that to a **UIImage**.

Weird thing is.... when I check the size of the **UIImage**, it's printing out the pixel width NOT the point width.

aka... `CGImageGetWidth(image) == imageToCrop.size.width`

Clearly this is not correct, as the size of a **UIImage** is supposed to be in points.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size?language=objc

> The logical dimensions of the image, measured in points.

Running iOS 11.1

```
CVImageBufferRef lastPixelBuffer; // assume this is filled already
...
CGImageRef image;
(void)VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(lastPixelBuffer, NULL, &image);
UIImage *imageToCrop = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:workingImage];

NSLog(@"image.width = %zu", CGImageGetWidth(image));
NSLog(@"photoToCrop.size.width = %f", photoToCrop.size.width);
NSLog(@"photoToCrop.scale = %f", photoToCrop.scale);
NSLog(@"underlying CGimageRef, width = %zu", CGImageGetWidth(photoToCrop.CGImage));
```

2017-11-02 16:16:00.895449-0400 TestBed[3950:1202023] image.width = 1080

2017-11-02 16:16:00.895515-0400 TestBed[3950:1202023] photoToCrop.size.width = 1080.000000

2017-11-02 16:16:00.895558-0400 TestBed[3950:1202023] photoToCrop.scale = 1.000000

2017-11-02 16:16:00.895663-0400 TestBed[3950:1202023] underlying CGimageRef, width = 1080

Comment: Hmmm... Doesn't the **Pixel** part of `lastPixelBuffer` and `VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer` imply actual *pixels*? Plus, from Apple's docs: `CGImageGetWidth()` *"Return Value - The width, in pixels, of the specified bitmap image (or image mask)."* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456148-cgimagegetwidth

Comment: @DonMag right of course. What I'm saying is that when I check the "size" property of the UIImage that I create with the CGImageRef, that size property is reporting pixel size NOT point size. I linked the UIImage doc.

Comment: `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]` ... *"Applying a scale factor of 1.0 results in an image whose size matches the pixel-based dimensions of the image."* I'm assuming using the shortcut version uses a default value of 1.0 for the scale factor?

Comment: @DonMag that must be it. how stupid though?? does that imply it by default stretches the image by the native scale factor, and then shrinks it by it when displayed in the correct point-sized container??

Comment: @DonMag i added some log output. So the underlying CGImageRef clearly isn't being stretched.... but the UIImage size property is clearly emitting pixels values, in direct contrast to documentation.

Comment: What's the Scale property of the resulting UIImage?

Comment: @DonMag 1.0, just added that.

Comment: OK, so if the Scale property of the resulting UIImage is 1.0, then it seems correct that its Size property is equal to the actual Pixels?

Comment: @DonMag right that's what it's reporting. But this is in absolute contradiction to documentation and what it should be reporting lol.